# How can i write the query with limitation Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra

I have query in Python to access cassandra.

```
select * from my_table where crate_date < ??
```

I found it but it doesn't help me

```
date.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
```

Gives error.

I dont know what should I do. I want to get before 2 day. For ex. if `create_date` new than 2 days, it will show.

Any suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: What error do you get?